# Difference between Session and Data in WixSharp?

Tags: wix, wixsharp

I´m creating an installer with WixSharp and i´m having some issues while trying to understand the difference between Session and Data. When should i use each one and what are they used for? Thanks!

I tried looking for Documentation but i only found the gitHub from wixsharp creators which has examples.

I expect the definition Session and data.A clear undertanding of what each does and what for.